# git show modify files but i don't change anything git reset did not work

Tags: git, line-endings, git-status

I clone repository switch to my branch and when i print git status i see modify files, i try to do git reset --hard but there was no effect :((

```
git status
On branch release

Changes not staged for commit:

    modified:   htdocs/fonts/OfficinaSansBoldC.eot
    modified:   htdocs/fonts/OfficinaSansBoldC.svg
    modified:   htdocs/fonts/OfficinaSansBoldC.ttf
    modified:   htdocs/fonts/OfficinaSansBoldC.woff
    modified:   htdocs/fonts/OfficinaSansC-Book.eot
    modified:   htdocs/fonts/OfficinaSansC-Book.svg
    modified:   htdocs/fonts/OfficinaSansC-Book.ttf
    modified:   htdocs/fonts/OfficinaSansC-Book.woff

no changes added to commit 

git reset --hard origin/release

git status
On branch release

Changes not staged for commit

    modified:   htdocs/fonts/officinasansboldc.eot
    modified:   htdocs/fonts/officinasansboldc.svg
    modified:   htdocs/fonts/officinasansboldc.ttf
    modified:   htdocs/fonts/officinasansboldc.woff
    modified:   htdocs/fonts/officinasansc-book.eot
    modified:   htdocs/fonts/officinasansc-book.svg
    modified:   htdocs/fonts/officinasansc-book.ttf
    modified:   htdocs/fonts/officinasansc-book.woff

no changes added to commit
```

Comment: See [`git clean -df`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean).

Comment: Please explain your question in the *body*.

Comment: git clean -df did't help

Comment: In your question, you write `autoclrf`, but the correct key is `core.autocrlf` (note that "r" and "l" are swapped). Is that a typo in your question or in your config file? Did you edit your config file manually?

Comment: I have problem with modified files and i print my .git/config core options for more understanding my situation

Comment: i would do git diff htdocs/fonts/officinasansc-book.woff and see what's actually changed , it's probably a file permission issue... you can also try git reset --hard

Comment: diff --git a/htdocs/fonts/officinasansc-book.woff b/htdocs/fonts/officinasansc-b
index f65eecc..11f16fa 100644
Binary files a/htdocs/fonts/officinasansc-book.woff and b/htdocs/fonts/officinas

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git line endings - can't stash, reset and now can't rebase over spurious line endings commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122094/git-line-endings-cant-stash-reset-and-now-cant-rebase-over-spurious-line-en)

Answer (score 10):

The issue with having a core.autocrlf to input is that it can change eol (end of lines) characters even for (binary) documents that should not be touched.

Try:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
git clone /url/your/repo
```

(meaning clone again your repo, and see if those diffs are still there)

---

With git 2.8 (March 2016), you will able to quickly check if those changes are eol-related.

See [commit a7630bd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a7630bd4274a0dff7cff8b92de3d3f064e321359) (16 Jan 2016) by [Torsten Bögershausen (`tboegi`)](https://github.com/tboegi).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 05f1539](https://github.com/git/git/commit/05f1539b7fb4809a406feaa8434bc2c58155d13d), 03 Feb 2016)</sup>

> ### `ls-files`: add eol diagnostics
>
> When working in a cross-platform environment, a user may want to check if text files are stored normalized in the repository and if `.gitattributes` are set appropriately.
>
> Make it possible to let Git show the line endings in the index and in the working tree and the effective text/eol attributes.
>
> The end of line ("`eolinfo`") are shown like this:

```
"-text"        binary (or with bare CR) file
"none"         text file without any EOL
"lf"           text file with LF
"crlf"         text file with CRLF
"mixed"        text file with mixed line endings.
```

> The effective text/eol attribute is one of these:

```
"", "-text", "text", "text=auto", "text eol=lf", "text eol=crlf"
```

> `git ls-files --eol` gives an output like this:

```
i/none   w/none   attr/text=auto      t/t5100/empty
i/-text  w/-text  attr/-text          t/test-binary-2.png
i/lf     w/lf     attr/text eol=lf    t/t5100/rfc2047-info-0007
i/lf     w/crlf   attr/text eol=crlf  doit.bat
i/mixed  w/mixed  attr/               locale/XX.po
```

> **to show what eol convention is used in the data in the index ('`i`'),
>   and in the working tree ('`w`'), and what attribute is in effect,
>   for each path that is shown**.

Comment: this helped me, I didn't have to clone the repo again

Comment: when in doubt "clone your repo again"

Answer (score 4):

I also met same problem.
When i run command `git diff`, the result is:

```
Binary files a/app/webroot/font-awesome-4.4.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf and b/app/webroot/font-awesome-4.4.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf differ
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in app/webroot/font-awesome-4.4.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
```

I tried `git reset --hard .` but it did not work.
But when `*.ttf binary` is appended into `.gitattributes` file, the `reset` command worked.

Cheer.

Comment: For me also helped adding `*.svg binary` to `.gitattributes` and doing `reset --hard`. Weird.

Comment: I needed to commit the `.gitattributes` diff and remove and add the `.ttf` file in order for this to work with git version 2.21.0 (Apple Git-120).

Answer (score 0):

The reason it does not work is conflicting line ending info passed to git. Try:

```
git ls-files --eol | grep /path/to/problematic/file
```

You can add a line to .git/info/attributes file to mitigate the problem. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53937415/281545) for details