# Git with autocrlf=false still produces "warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF" messages

Tags: git, core.autocrlf

I am using Git version 1.9.1 on Ubuntu 14.04.

I have tested the `core.autocrlf` behaviour in a fresh repo with a DOS-format and a Unix-format file and confirmed that `git add` with `autocrlf=true` does, as expected, produce a warning: `LF will be replaced by CRLF in ...` message for the Unix-format file, and produces no messages for either file when `autocrlf=false`. (I'm not clear in this case why it decided to use DOS line endings rather than Unix ones in the repo, but I'm not sure that's important here.)

However, in another repo, despite having `autocrlf=true`, it keeps telling me that it's going to convert some files:

```
$ git config core.autocrlf
false
$ git add lib/node_modules/pulp/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-core/node_modules/source-list-map/test/fixtures/from-to-tests/null-source.input.map
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in lib/node_modules/pulp/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-core/node_modules/source-list-map/test/fixtures/from-to-tests/null-source.input.map.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
$
```

I can't figure out why it's doing this. I'm looking for either an explanation of the problem or clues on how to debug it.

Additional notes:

- No, there isn't a `.gitattributes` file in the repo. But it raises an interesting point, should it make a difference if `autocrlf` is set to false?
- And no, I just checked carefully and the file has a 0x0a after every 0x0d, and a 0x0d before every 0x0a.

Comment: Is there a `.gitattributes` file?

Comment: Are there `.gitattributes` files?  If so, what settings do they specify?

Comment: Does the file have a mixture of `CRLF` and `LF` ?

Comment: Updated the question to answer your good queries. Thanks.

Comment: "But it raises an interesting point, should it make a difference if autocrlf is set to false?" Apparently, it does. I got the same message and had core.autocrlf `false`. But, in my case, there really was a ".gitattributes" file containing line `* text=auto`. Once I removed it, the conversion warning (and hopefully, the conversion itself) went away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, setting `core.autocrlf` to `false` is often a good idea: see "[Handling line ending in GIT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50771174/6309)".

Second, make sure `core.autocrlf` is actually false when queried in the parent folder of the file to add:

```
git -C lib/node_modules/[...]/fixtures/from-to-tests/ config core.autocrlf
```

Check also the problem would still persist today (June 2018, Git 2.17.1)

Third, that warning was introduced in Feb. 2008 (Git v1.5.5) in [commit 21e5ad5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/21e5ad50fc5e7277c74cfbb3cf6502468e840f86) by [Steffen Prohaska (sprohaska)](https://github.com/sprohaska).

> for binary files that are accidentally classified as text the conversion can corrupt data.

You might have checked text files, but ignored binary files.

Finally, a good way to detect, since Git 2.8 (March 2016) files affected by eol setting, is to use:

```
git ls-files --eol
```

See "[git shows modified files, but I didn't change anything and `git reset` did not work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27577906/6309)".

Answer (score 0):

It seems that beside `git config --local core.autocrlf false`, the  core.safecrlf must be also updated

```
git config --local core.safecrlf false
```