# Handeling line ending in GIT

Tags: git, newline, core.autocrlf

Let's say we have team of 10 developers. Half of them use Windows and half Linux. All of them work together on a project, sharing work using GIT. Problem with CRLF/LF begins ...

Exmaple: One developer with Window works on the same thing together with developer which is using Linux. Both of them need to view/edit the same files.

Will there be problem with CRLF and LF ? What are the ways GIT would handle this problem ? (force Linux isn't solution)

Comment: The default for Git on Windows is to check text files out with CRLF and commit them as LF. This usually works fine and you shouldn’t have a problem.

Comment: If you know enough to tag this question with `core.autocrlf`, you know enough to try this out yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see more with the recent article "[Git for Windows: Line Endings](https://www.edwardthomson.com/blog/git_for_windows_line_endings.html)" from **[Edward Thomson](https://www.edwardthomson.com/about/)** (Ex-GitHubber, now Microsoft, now... errr GitHubber again)

> The key to dealing with line endings is to **make sure your configuration is committed to the repository, using `.gitattributes`**. For most people, this is as simple as creating a file named `.gitattributes` at the root of your repository that contains one line:

```
* text=auto
```

> With this set, Windows users will have text files converted from Windows style line endings (\r\n) to Unix style line endings (\n) when they’re added to the repository.
>
> ### Why not `core.autocrlf`?
>
> Originally, Git for Windows introduced a different approach for line endings that you may have seen: `core.autocrlf`. This is a similar approach to the attributes mechanism: the idea is that a Windows user will set a Git configuration option `core.autocrlf=true` and their line endings will be converted to Unix style line endings when they add files to the repository.
>
> The difference between these two options is subtle, but critical: the `.gitattributes` is set in the repository, so its shared with everybody. But `core.autocrlf` is set in the local Git configuration. That means that everybody has to remember to set it, and set it identically.

I would add that `core.autocrlf` applies to *all* files including binaries ones, whereas `.gitattribure` `core.eol` directive can be set for specific files (like `*.cpp` for instance)

I have [always recommended that `.gitattributes` approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35268716/6309).