# Cannot reset changes in Git Extensions

Tags: git, git-svn, git-extensions

I am using Git Extensions for connecting to GitHub. Recently I have faced there are files that are flagged in unstaged changes. I cannot reset/delete files. The only way to get rid of them is check-in the files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Had the same problem and in my case it was caused because someone in my team added the ['.gitattributes'](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) file with a line:

```
*   text=auto
```

Removing this file and checking in the pending changes solved the issue.

There are other posts about that can help: [Discard changes in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575682/cant-seem-to-discard-changes-in-git) and [Git line endings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122094/git-line-endings-cant-stash-reset-and-now-cant-rebase-over-spurious-line-en?lq=1)