# How do I make git accept mode changes without accepting all text changes?

Tags: git, chmod

I've got the opposite problem from "[How do I make git ignore mode changes (chmod)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580596/how-do-i-make-git-ignore-mode-changes-chmod)" I've got a file that I've changed executable permission on, but there are also some text changes, and I want to commit the former but not the latter. Is this possible with git?

(Actually, I've made some text changes I want to commit along with the executable permission change, and others I don't want to commit)

**Update:** Unstaging the text changes to the file, and then doing git add -p again and incorporating some of the text changes managed to get the mode change into staging. (My git version is 1.5.4.3)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`git add -i` will let you selectively add some hunks from a file to the index.  I don't know whether or not it's sensitive to permissions, but if you were to add a hunk after the `chmod` operation, it might end up in the index correctly even without explicitly updating the permission.

Comment: That's correct, git add -i (and git add --patch) ask you "Stage mode change?" right before they ask about the changed hunks.

Comment: Thanks Phil. That ability seems to be associated with git 1.5.6 according to the release notes. (Unfortunately, my git isn't that recent)

Answer (score 83):

You should be able to do:

```
git update-index --chmod=(+|-)x <file>
```

to adjust the executable bit stored in the index.

You can then commit this separately from any changes to the files content.

Comment: **Note:** use "git commit" (with "git add" if necessary, not "git commit -a".  This solution has the advantage in that it works even with ancient git.

Comment: And it also works on filesystems with poor permission support! Even Windows!

Comment: This solution is way better, @Andrew Grimm. Accept this answer instead, please.

Answer (score 3):

[Charles’ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1611681)
was adding both file mode and content changes to the index for me. I worked around it like this.

```
git update-index --skip-worktree --chmod=+x <file>
git update-index --no-skip-worktree <file>
```

[Example](http://github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/351fb29/scripts/git-chmod.sh#L26-L27)

Alternatively you can do

```sh
git update-index --chmod=+x <file>
git config interactive.singlekey 1
echo na | git reset -p
```