# How can I get git to read mode changes?

Tags: git, permissions, git-svn, mode, folder-permissions

I've changed permissions on a folder and want to push it out to the repository. However, git doesn't recognize the permission changes.

Any idea why not and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Git & directory modes:**

In short, you would need extensions to commit directory modes and permissions in general. See this question:

[How does git handle folder permission?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1071241/1175253) --> http://joeyh.name/code/etckeeper/

**Git & file modes (regular files only):**

Use [git-config(1)](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) to see, how git is configured:

`git config core.filemode` or `git config --global core.filemode` respectively

`git config core.filemode true` would enable mode change awareness.

Note:

- Any local setting will override the corresponding `--gobal` setting (in case of doubt, I would recommend to change the local config first).
- `core.filemode` applies to the x bit of regular files only.

See also:

- [How do I make Git ignore file mode (chmod) changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1580596/1175253)
- [How do I make git accept mode changes without accepting all text changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1611211/1175253)