# Push core.filemode setting to remote

Tags: git

I have a particular repository that I would like to set the configuration option `core.filemode=false` on (using `git config core.filemode false`), but have it retained for every clone going forward. Is there a way to push this setting to the origin so I don't have to remember it every time I clone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be no way to push this setting to a remote server and have it preserved. Every clone must remember to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The way I deal with this is by adding this to `~/.bashrc`:

```sh
PROMPT_COMMAND='
if [ -d .git ]
then
  if [ ! -g .git/config ]
  then
    git config core.filemode 0
    chmod +s .git/config
  fi
fi
'
```

- [Git ignoring gitconfig?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10376913/#10377092)
- [Saving files with Windows programs makes Git in Cygwin track filemode changes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26906254/#26915317)