# Can I make git diff ignore permission changes

Tags: git, diff

I inadvertedly change the permissions of my entire tree and commit that change along with other content changes.

I use something like :

```
tar -czf deploy.tar git diff --name-only v1 v2
```

to generate  a tar with the modified files between two tags, the problem is that now because of the permissions change almost all my tree is listed as modified.

Is there a way that I could tell `git diff` to ignore those files which only has the permissions changed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make git ignore mode changes (chmod)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580596/how-do-i-make-git-ignore-mode-changes-chmod)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use the `-G<regex>` option ("Look for differences whose patch text contains added/removed lines that match `<regex>`.") searching for any changes at all - i.e. `.`. Permissions-only changes don't match this, so they are ignored.

So: `git diff -G.`

Comment: For some reason this solution is incompatible with `--ignore-space-at-eol`. If I do `git diff -G. revA..revB` then I suppress reporting of mode changes, as desired, but I do see line-ending changes. If I add `--ignore-space-at-eol` I suppress line-ending changes, as desired, but the mode changes come back. Why would that be? They don't seem fundamentally related, to me. I want to suppress both.

Comment: This does not work with changes to binary files, i.e. any binary file change will not show in the diff, if you use -G.

Comment: Found out that the trick works if you also add "--text"

Answer (score 178):

This will tell git to ignore permissions:

```
git config core.filemode false
```

Comment: Maybe this could prevent adding files with changed permissions to a commit, but in my case the files are committed, pushed and tagged, and the command you propose doesn't help me. I guess I'll have to make some kind of bash script to parse the output of git diff to remove the lines about mode changes, and feed the result to tar. Any ideas are more then welcome

Comment: @Cesar: The command tells git to ignore permissions differences between the index and the working copy.  Isn't that what you want?

Comment: i'm new to git, but the thing is that the differences is between commits. When i do git diff tag1 tag2, it show all the files to which i changed the permissions besides the files with modified content, i just want to find a way to ignore all those 'mode change 664 => 775', I hope I made myself clear

Comment: @Cesar: Oh!  So you've already committed the changed permissions?  Sorry, I had missed that part.  If you haven't already pushed the changes to another repository or merged them to another branch, I'd suggest amending/rebaseing the commit to fix it.

Comment: `git diff -G.` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388811/show-git-diff-ignoring-file-permission-changes)

Comment: To make this setting global, you could use the --global option: $ git config --global core.filemode false

Comment: The dot (`.`) at the end of `gif diff -G.`**matters**

Answer (score 15):

I had this problem after intentionally removing the execute permission from source code files (~26K files).  Then, git diff says that all files have changed!  The answer with `core.filemode` does not help me since that only affects diffs against your working dir, not diffs against 2 commits in the repo.

The answer was to use the (big scary) filter-branch command.  In particular, all you need to type is:

```
git filter-branch -f --tree-filter 'find * -type f | xargs chmod 644' -- --all
```

from the root of your working dir.  Of course, be sure to make a copy of your repo first, i.e.

```
cp -pr ~/repo.git ~/repo-orig.git
```

or similar, in case you need to re-try.

Enjoy!

Comment: Interesting (+1). I have included it in my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/12979453/6309 (since your own answer was deleted)