# Mercurial: Ignore file permission / mode (chmod) changes

Tags: git, mercurial, permissions, file-permissions, chmod

Is there a way to ignore file permission / mode (chmod) changes for a Mercurial repository?

I'm looking for a setting similar to Git's:

```
core.filemode -> false
```

- as described here:

[Can I make git diff ignore permission changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290512/can-i-make-git-diff-ignore-permission-changes)

Update: the correct answer is Ry4an's together with my second comment to his answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mercurial only tracks the execute permission on files and not in a user/group/other way, just as a single bit, so depending what you're trying to squelch it's possible you really need to just adjust the `umask` of the user running `hg update`'

If it is the execute bit that's getting you, then I think the only option is to use a pre-commit hook like:

```
[hooks]
pre-commit = find $(hg root) -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod a-x
```

that, removes execute from all files before committing.

To do the same only on versioned files, use `hg locate` as pointed out in [Ish's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1596966/lsh) comment:

```
[hooks]
pre-commit = hg locate --print0 | xargs -0 chmod a-x
```

Note, though, that this can fail under certain circumstances. For example during renames (`hg rename`) both the file before the rename and after the rename will be recorded as versioned using `hg locate`. Therefore the hook will fail to `chmod` the old name of the file and the commit will fail as a whole. This can be "fixed" by either disabling the hook temporarily or by calling `/bin/true` at the end of the hook.

Comment: I'm not sure whether that command will fix it. I don't want to change my umask (which is a secure 700 or 077 if you like), but I'm not bothered by running a chmod command before commit (even manually).

The problem is however that I ran that command manually and it didn't fix a thing.

`hg status` still shows modified files,

`hg diff` shows no differences and 

`hg diff --git` will always say that the permissions were changed (to the current ones - no matter what the old ones and the new ones were)

What can I do?

Comment: An update: your answer is basically correct; the problem is that my repoository contains tens of thousands of files each with their own specific "x" bit permissions. In my new local copy I was basically trying to do a global chmod for all files - which contradicted the specific "x" permissions for each of the files (that Mercurial had stored). I think I'll just commit the "x" bit for ALL files. This is definitely something that can't hurt the production server.

Comment: I had the www-data user creating files, owned by www-data so attempting to modify them through a permission error and exited early. this worked for me to target only versioned files: `pre-commit = hg locate --print0 | xargs -0 chmod a-x`

Comment: This is not working for me. How can I fix this? I am missing something?

Comment: You'll need to be a lot more specific about how its' not working for you.