# In Mercurial is it possible to commit only the contents of a file, not its meta-data (e.g. permissions)?

Tags: mercurial

Following problem. If I am comparing files on a Linux box via CIFS on a Windows box with WinMerge, WinMerge appears to touch the file permission. Notably it adds the `x` bit sometimes in the `u` and sometimes both in the `u` and the `g` field.

How can I either

- revert the permissions, without reverting the file contents, or
- commit the file contents without committing the changes to the permissions?

The odd part is that `hg stat` lists those files as changed, but an `hg diff` then only yields the diff of the single file that has changed content, out of a bunch of files shown in `hg stat`. What gives?

Comment: One thing that might help is using `hg diff --git` to see the changed permissions.

Comment: Yep, in some corner of my mind I knew there was some diff output that had the information. Should make the `diff = diff --git` an alias. Thanks.

Comment: No need for the alias, you can set the `git = True` option in the `[diff]` section of your `.hgrc`.

Comment: I have the situation where a working directory updated with Windows version of hg is clean on windows, but shows modified files on Linux. `hg diff --git` is empty, it seems that it is impossible to see what makes the difference.

Comment: Maybe this one is helpful? :) 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073115/mercurial-ignore-file-permission-mode-chmod-changes