# How can I make `hg status` to show only the files that `hg diff` show

Tags: mercurial

There are more number of files that gets printed out with `hg status` because it shows all files with changes, including permissions. `hg diff` on the other hand, ignores permissions.
If I want to have a workflow where permission on the source tree is ignored, what kind of configuration do I need?

Comment: "status may appear to disagree with diff if permissions have changed **or
       a merge has occurred.** The standard diff format does not report
       permission changes and diff only reports changes relative to one merge
       parent." Do you also want to ignore changes in the other parent of a merge?

Comment: @alexis Not ignore all changes, but only the permission changes. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen any evidence that what you ask for is possible. But your question is basically a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5073115/699305) from 2011, which suggests the obvious work-around: Add a commit hook to normalize the permissions of your files, so that they don't change when you don't expect them to. Whether that's useful to you depends on why you need this fix in the first place.

Comment: The solution you have mentioned does not work for me, because these are files for web application in production. I guess I could go through the hassle of copying the files and then working with the mercurial hooks. uwsgi and nginx need more lenient permission, while the files on the repo is restrictive.