# How do i ignore file mode on mercurial hg

Tags: mercurial

I want to ignore file mode,such as `chmod 777 somefile`.

I'm looking for a setting similar to Git's:

core.filemode = false

Answer (score 2):

Mercurial only tracks the *execute* permission on files. In order to avoid tracking it a solution has been posted here: [Mercurial: Ignore file permission / mode (chmod) changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073115/mercurial-ignore-file-permission-mode-chmod-changes).