# Working with python off of a FAT32 filesystem

Tags: python, django, git, filesystems, fat32

I pulled a django project repository (git) to a FAT32 drive and made some changes but when I went to commit, every file is out of date because of it's mode (i.e. - was 100644 is 100755) that's because of FAT32 right? I haven't ever really thought about this, do I just need to work off of a different filesystem or is this not a big deal in the long run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to tell Git to ignore the file permissions.  See this question: [How do I make Git ignore file mode (chmod) changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580596/how-do-i-make-git-ignore-mode-changes-chmod)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use FAT32 unless you really have to. There are several reasons for this ranging from memory, CPU, speed, lack of security, lack of journaling and even that FAT32 is more difficult to recover when disaster strikes. You can convert FAT32 to NTFS using [Convert](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307881).

Part from that FAT32 doesn't have "modes" for files except the usual flags Archive, ReadOnly and Hidden (and System?). Some OS can however put some metadata files into the directories to simulate "better" filesystems. Windows will not do this.

So my guess is that this is not a FAT32 problem.

Comment: There are plenty of reasons to use FAT32, so you shouldn't really say shouldn't ever use it. But I agree, it's definitely not the best for a general purpose file system.

Comment: In this case I don't have to use FAT32 so I've just moved to a different partition.