# Heroku -> Python: Using subprocess to launch an executable gets [Permission Denied]

Tags: python, heroku, chess, python-chess

## The problem:

I have a python webapp running on heroku which creates a subprocess for communication with the [Stockfish](https://stockfishchess.org/) chess engine.

Everything *JustWorks™* on my local machine, however upon attempting to deploy the project on Heroku, I get an error saying `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied`

Below, I have included the heroku logs from when I tried to deploy this.

I know other folks have heroku apps running the stockfish engine within the same dyno, however I haven't had much luck finding resources to assist me in getting it working. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

## The logs:

`` bash
2017-06-20T22:32:48.419694+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python server.py`
2017-06-20T22:32:51.933668+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-06-20T22:32:51.933687+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "server.py", line 23, in <module>
2017-06-20T22:32:51.933882+00:00 app[web.1]:     engine = chess.uci.popen_engine(DIR_PATH + "/stockfish_8_x64")
2017-06-20T22:32:51.933884+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chess/uci.py", line 1405, in popen_engine
2017-06-20T22:32:51.934623+00:00 app[web.1]:     PopenProcess(engine, command, **kwargs)
2017-06-20T22:32:51.934625+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/chess/uci.py", line 404, in __init__
2017-06-20T22:32:51.934874+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.process = subprocess.Popen(command, **popen_args)
2017-06-20T22:32:51.934877+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
2017-06-20T22:32:51.935286+00:00 app[web.1]:     restore_signals, start_new_session)
2017-06-20T22:32:51.935288+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1326, in _execute_child
2017-06-20T22:32:51.935988+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
2017-06-20T22:32:51.936008+00:00 app[web.1]: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
2017-06-20T22:32:52.051035+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-06-20T22:32:52.035235+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1 ``

Comment: I assume that you have the `stockfish` executable in `git`? If so, you'll need to check that the file has execute permissions. For example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476513/git-file-permissions-on-windows (the command still applies, even if you are already on *nix)

Comment: How do I do that on Heroku, when the dyno gets torn down and restarted each time? Should I do that as part of the Procfile command? `web: chmod +x stockfish_8_x64 && python server.py`

Comment: Git can and should preserve file permissions. I would check - **1)** what permissions git has via `git ls-files HEAD` (or branch name). The last 3 digits of the first field are the file mode, in octal. Then **2)** what permissions are on the Heroku filesystem (via `heroku run 'ls -al'`). Then **3)** if git perms don't have execute, add it and redeploy. Finally, **4)** if that doesn't address the issue, then find a way to patch perms on app start (in-app, via `os.chmod()`, rather than Procfile).

Comment: Thanks @bimsapi, the 4th option, adding the chmod permissions in-app worked like a charm!

Comment: I got a very similar problem. How do you include the `os.chmod()`? Maybe you can help me on my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72838592/heroku-permission-for-subprocess

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question based off the comments:
The stockfish executable did not have executable rights on the heroku server, and those needed to be added explicitly. As per guidance in the comments on the original question, I was able to modify my server.py to append the executable permission to the stockfish executable file.

[Source -> SO: Simple chmod +x in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791997/how-do-you-do-a-simple-chmod-x-from-within-python)