# chmod -R 775 for Windows 10

Tags: php, windows, laravel, content-management-system

I try to install atlantics cms by the composer installation on windows 10 , but the `chmod -R 775` command doesn't work for the composer  it generate the following error:

> php artisan atlantis: key: generate
>   Atlantis key [mCo2B8o6os5mdqyogTpb9a9WaTCpA4CU] set successfully.
>   **> chmod -R 775 storage
>   'chmod' is not recognized as an internal command
>   or external, an executable program or a batch file.
>   Script chmod -R 775 storage handling the post-create-project-cmd event returned with error code 1**

[screenchot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIWgY.png)

How do I set files permission  manually or by cmd?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git file permissions on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476513/git-file-permissions-on-windows)

Comment: Hi. This doesn't seem related to git, as it is a php command that is executed that end up trying to change file permissions. Can you clarify why you think this is git-related? Also, it would be better if you copied and pasted the actual text into your question instead of a screenshot.

Comment: CACLS files /e /p {USERNAME}:{PERMISSION} https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928738/how-to-grant-permission-to-users-for-a-directory-using-command-line-in-windows