# looking for ideas to make sure file permissions are set to chmod 777 in a git repository

Tags: git

We are using Git and GitHub

We have both Windows and Linux developers in our team.

The application will finally run on a Linux distribution.

Some of the files must have execute permission set (let's say `chmod 777` for the sake of simplicity)

Is there any way for the Windows git clients to set the Linux file permissions in a git repository?

**Conclusion**

Use `git update-index --chmod=+x <file>` to set the permissions as @lavanya answered.

Use `git ls-files -s` to see the permissions. see this post explains how read the 6 digit mode number :[How to read the mode field of git-ls-tree's output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737673/how-to-read-the-mode-field-of-git-ls-trees-output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can do it .

For example following command adds user execute permission to an arbitrary file:

```
git update-index --chmod=+x <file>
```

check this link
[Git file permissions on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476513/git-file-permissions-on-windows)

Comment: Just to make the approach complete, is there anyway to see the permission of a file using git for windows?

Comment: try using this command git ls-tree HEAD or git ls-files --stage