# How to preserve the permissions of files when pushing to GIT

Tags: git, file-permissions

We have a zip file where all project(Laravel) files are stored. Since there is no known way of extracting files inside git, what we did was to extract the files, and then pushed the directory to git.

Everything is working except;

1. empty folders were not uploaded, we added a .gitkeep file to all empty folders to keep them
2. the permissions were not preserved. for this problem, we still havent found a solution.

Any advice related would be highly appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to chmod the files you want ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32717779/6309)), add, commit and push.

But keep in mind only 644 and 755 are versioned with Git.
You have [scripts which can updates the permissions on changed files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71656818/6309).