# How to mass-resolve Git Conflicts with only File Mode changes?

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge

I am trying to merge two repositories, and there are only a couple of "real" conflicts, but there are about 70 file conflicts of "Both added". When viewing a git diff, however, it only shows file mode changed.

What would be the best way to mass-accept the current file mode and ignore the incoming file mode?

A little background:
These 2 repositories are of the same code, but one has been tracked through SVN, so doesn't have a history. I'm using git-svn to track it now and merge it with the current git repository.

The incoming conflicts on merge appear as:
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in framework/file/name.php
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

Git status shows:
both added: framework/file/name.php

If I use the git mergetool, it does not show any conflicts. Going through each file using this method takes a very long time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So after trying all the various merge strategies, and determining that I needed to take the file mode from the repository, discarding the local file mode, the best solution I came up was to use:
`git checkout --theirs <remote/branch> -- path` for the filemode changes, and used `git mergetool` for the code conflict resolution.
Using git diff, I could see which files were filemode changes, and which were file code changes.
`git merge` uses `--recursive -Xours` as the default merge strategy.

There is a git config variable: core.fileMode that can ignore file mode changes.
See: [How do I make Git ignore file mode (chmod) changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580596/how-do-i-make-git-ignore-mode-changes-chmod)

Answer (score 1):

How about `git merge -Xours branchToMergeIn`?  It will merge the two and give preference to your current branch.  Never tried it with mode changes, but *should* do the trick...

edited with jeffromi's merge strategy.

Comment: There were other real conflicts that needed to be resolved, and some code that needed to be pulled in. By running `git merge -s ours remote/branch` it said: "Merge made by ours", yet running git status shows nothing changed... no new commits, no conflicts. Nothing.

Comment: So it never created a merge commit?  You'd have to look at `git log` to see the commits, `git status` won't show you any commits.  If you want to selectively merge somethings, and not others, I don't think you have much of a choice about going through each file...

Comment: When tracking master it would show commits ahead of master, I forgot to track master, so after doing that, it shows it's ahead by 301 commits. However, when running git show <commit id> on the merge commit, it's not showing any diff or file changes. So not sure on that one. Thanks for your help so far. :)

Comment: Actually, it might have worked... I see the commits in the history, although the merge doesn't show a diff, I'm not sure it should. Now I just need to find a way to see if the changes were applied as they should have been.

Comment: @Highway: By default, `git show` (and similar commands) do not print diffs for merge commits. To see the diff, try `git show -c`. Additionally, `gitk` by default does show merge diffs.

Comment: Also, note that `git merge -s ours` means "record a merge, but use the content from the current branch" - it completely ignores the other branch's content. If you want to just resolve conflicts in favor of the current branch, while doing all non-conflicting merges normally, you want `git merge -Xours`. See [`man git-merge`, under merge strategies](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html#_merge_strategies).