# Git merge - symlink conflict

Tags: git, git-merge, symlink

After merging I got a symbolic links conflict:

```
$ git status
[SKIP]
both added:      file.txt
[SKIP]
```

Git diff doesn't show the target values:

```
$ git diff
[SKIP]
diff --cc file.txt
index 5873c9d,e31df9a..0000000
--- a/file.txt
+++ b/file.txt
```

Is there a simple way to compare symbolic link target values?

Comment: That's curious; Git *should* show the symlink contents. It does normally, e.g., comparing a symlink to the empty string when a new symlink is created. Perhaps the special combined diff from an in-progress merge is missing some code.

Comment: Are they really symlink? Or just regular files, with a different file mode? (https://stackoverflow.com/q/6835796/6309)

Comment: @VonC yes, real symlinks. If you resolve one it will point to an actual target file. And the target files are different - let's imagine `file.txt` from branch1 points to `text/file_v3.txt` and `file.txt` from master points to `text/file_v2.txt`. I'd like to have a simple command that will show the symlinks diff:
```-text/file_v2.txt
+text/file_v3.txt```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using git show, you could display the target for that link.
I just tested it on a test repo, with a link referencing the file one or the file two in different branches.
The merge has a conflict:

```
vonc@voncavn7:/mnt/d/git/tests/sml/a$ git commit -m "add link from one"
[one 22b4906] add link from one
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 120000 link
vonc@voncavn7:/mnt/d/git/tests/sml/a$ git merge -s recursive two
Auto-merging link
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in link
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
vonc@voncavn7:/mnt/d/git/tests/sml/a$ git diff
diff --cc link
index 43dd47e,1ed3c7a..0000000
--- a/link
+++ b/link
```

But I can see which one points to which:

```
vonc@voncavn7:/mnt/d/git/tests/sml/a$ git show :2:link
one
vonc@voncavn7:/mnt/d/git/tests/sml/a$ git show :3:link
zero
```

---

Note that with Git 2.16.x/2.17, you would be able to resolve it automatically, should you chose a merge *option*.
That is because "`git merge -Xours/-Xtheirs`" learned to use our/their version when resolving a conflicting updates to a symbolic link.

See [commit fd48b46](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fd48b464747c275b3d014b3f14d60d9ac19d184a) (26 Sep 2017) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 14b9d9a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/14b9d9aa0d2fc6fd81d7a392fc1cc951a9d9d115), 23 Jan 2018)</sup>

> ### `merge`: teach `-Xours`/`-Xtheirs` to symbolic link merge

> The `-Xours`/`-Xtheirs` merge options were originally defined as a way
> to "force" the resolution of 3way textual merge conflicts to take
> one side without using your editor, hence did not even trigger in
> situations where you would normally not get the `<<< === >>>` conflict
> markers.
>
> This was improved for binary files back in 2012 with [a944af1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a944af1d86e6171d68ed2a3aa67b1d68f00e1fe8)
> ("merge: teach `-Xours`/`-Xtheirs` to binary ll-merge driver",
> 2012-09-08, Git v1.7.12.4).
>
> Teach a similar trick to the codepath that deals with merging two
> conflicting changes to symbolic links.

---

Note that with Git 2.24 (Q4 2019), a bug in merge-recursive code that triggers when a branch with a symbolic link is merged with a branch that replaces it with a
directory has been fixed.

See [commit 83e3ad3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/83e3ad3b126125d23eea10283d85682a1a680daa) (18 Sep 2019) by [Jonathan Tan (`jhowtan`)](https://github.com/jhowtan).
Helped-by: [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1f4485b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1f4485b2194f662d82968bd6110fa63153df5298), 07 Oct 2019)</sup>

> ### `merge-recursive`: symlink's descendants not in way

> When the working tree has:
>
> ```
> - bar (directory)
> - bar/file (file)
> - foo (symlink to .)
> ```
>
> (note that `lstat()` for "`foo/bar`" would tell us that it is a directory)
>
> and the user merges a commit that deletes the foo symlink and instead contains:
>
> ```
> - bar (directory, as above)
> - bar/file (file, as above)
> - foo (directory)
> - foo/bar (file)
> ```
>
> the merge should happen without requiring user intervention.
> However, this does not happen.
>
> This is because `dir_in_way()`, when checking the working tree, thinks
> that "`foo/bar`" is a directory.
> But a symlink should be treated much the same as a file: since `dir_in_way()` is only checking to see if there is a directory in the way, we don't want symlinks in leading paths to sometimes cause `dir_in_way()` to return true.
>
> Teach `dir_in_way()` to also check for symlinks in leading paths before reporting whether a directory is in the way.

---

With Git 2.33 (Q3 2021), the "union" conflict resolution variant misbehaved when used with binary merge driver.

See [commit 382b601](https://github.com/git/git/commit/382b601acde12b298bb84faa11b3f42868716a0d), [commit 7f53f78](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7f53f78b04b49c2060c23df6566aceb3ba394aea), [commit 7d879ad](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7d879ad7e02f1f4d7f504862b280e503db403a36) (10 Jun 2021) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 308528a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/308528a3eae30b7dc02fffe76b91af8a91cc1b01), 13 Jul 2021)</sup>

> ### [`ll_binary_merge()`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7d879ad7e02f1f4d7f504862b280e503db403a36): handle `XDL_MERGE_FAVOR_UNION`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>

> Prior to [commit a944af1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a944af1d86e6171d68ed2a3aa67b1d68f00e1fe8) ("`merge`: teach -Xours/-Xtheirs to binary ll-merge driver", 2012-09-08, Git v1.8.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e6d29a4b47cf476e18658609033bdee4c42db3b8) listed in [batch #7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5976753e732186d7f8a5c6af55a8ce3e2d2b677b)), we always reported a conflict from `ll_binary_merge()` by returning "1" (in the `xdl_merge` and `ll_merge` code, this value is the number of conflict hunks).
> After that commit, we report zero conflicts if the "variant" flag is set, under the assumption that it is one of `XDL_MERGE_FAVOR_OURS` or `XDL_MERGE_FAVOR_THEIRS`.
>
> But this gets confused by `XDL_MERGE_FAVOR_UNION`.
> We do not know how to do a binary union merge, but erroneously report no conflicts anyway (and just blindly use the "ours" content as the result).
>
> Let's tighten our check to just the cases that [a944af1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a944af1d86e6171d68ed2a3aa67b1d68f00e1fe8) meant to cover.
> This fixes the union case (which existed already back when that commit was made), as well as future-proofing us against any other variants that get added later.
>
> Note that you can't trigger this from "[`git merge-file --union`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7d879ad7e02f1f4d7f504862b280e503db403a36/Documentation/git-merge-file.txt#L75)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt-file#Documentation/git-merge-file.txt---union))</sup>, as that bails on binary files before even calling into the ll-merge machinery.

Comment: thank you. `git merge -Xours/-Xtheirs` worked well for me.

Comment: @DmitryPetrov Great! Although it should not be available yet... did you recompiled Git?

Comment: @DmitryPetrov OK, I'll do some more test.