# How to resolve Mode Changed conflicts while merging upstream

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, version-control, gitlab, conflict

I am working with Gitlab (GDK) and trying to update my current branch with upstream, everything works but there are 3K+ conflicts during the merge. I am sure that I just modified around 30 to 35 files then why I'm getting so many conflicts?

A little investigation reveals that most of the conflicts are due to ModeChanges (see image)'

[image]

This is how files look in **meld**

[image]

I'm not sure why I'm getting these conflicts, I've tried everything suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835796/how-to-mass-resolve-git-conflicts-with-only-file-mode-changes) but still unable to resolve the issue.

Any kind of help would be appreciated in this regard.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make Git ignore file mode (chmod) changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580596/how-do-i-make-git-ignore-file-mode-chmod-changes)

Comment: I tried changing the fileMode config. But it didn't work for me.