# How to share git repo between Mac and Windows running on VMWare?

Tags: git

I have a repo on our Enterprise GitHub. I cloned the repo on my Mac to /users/rams/MyProject

On the same machine I have Win7 running under VMWare. I have shared /users/rams/MyProject between the machines and it appears as drive Z on my Win7 machine. I have committed and pushed all my changed from Mac. However when I open the repo location on my Win7 the status say I have unstaged changes.

How is that possible?

What is the correct way to share a repo folder between Mac and Win7 hosted on VMWare?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure chmod changes are ignored

git config core.filemode false

[How do I make Git ignore file mode (chmod) changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580596/how-do-i-make-git-ignore-mode-changes-chmod)