# Is it possible to ignore git file mode change in my own ~/.gitconfig

Tags: git, git-config

From old thread: [How do I make Git ignore file mode (chmod) changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580596/how-do-i-make-git-ignore-mode-changes-chmod)

It seems to me that I need to do on every repository, right? Is it possible to set in my own ~/.gitconfig?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a bug, because running `git config --global core.fileMode false` doesn't work, but `git config core.fileMode false` or `git config --global core.filemode false` both do.

So pick one of those.

My `git --version` is `git version 1.7.10.4`