# Make git reset --hard to ignore permission changes

Tags: git

I'm trying to `git reset --hard origin/master` but make git somehow checkout the files only if the actual content of each file changed, instead of checking them even if only the permissions changed.

Is there some parameter I can pass to git reset or that's a thing that can be solved only with a script?

Comment: Maybe just commit only the permission changes, and then work from that point forward?

Comment: @KirilRaychev thing is that I do not want to commit the permission changes.

Comment: You could try committing to a detached head then rolling back to your branch to see if that solves it? But sounds like a bug worth filing against git if the latest version is still broken.

Comment: Is there a good use case for this? (what's the reason) - It maybe that an update to git could be proposed.

Comment: Maybe you need --assume-unchanged for the file, though you'll have to check the manual for all the implications of that assumption to are giving to git.

Comment: @PhilipOakley I'm deploying the git repo to a NGINX server and I'm then chmod-ing everything to read-only (for security, thou the NGINX user already can't write to the path where I deploy).

Comment: @alexandernst: Ah, so you are using git as a deployment tool. This is often not a good idea, as git is not meant as a deployment tool; you might consider some other solution. Still, if you get it to work, why not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue via [Git's ML](http://www.mail-archive.com/git@vger.kernel.org/msg30004.html).

So basically:

```
git update-index --refresh
```

before: `git reset` did the trick :)

Comment: Glad to hear it - can you edit the answer from the ML into this answer too please?

Answer (score 5):

Try setting `core.fileMode` to `false` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580596/how-do-i-make-git-ignore-mode-changes-chmod) ([docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#_variables)) (`git config core.fileMode false` should do the trick). This seems to make Git ignore any permission changes when hard resetting. Now, I did find that if Git couldn't read the file (e.g., I'd set the permissions to 000), a hard reset would restore the original permissions it was committed with.

Another thought, which might be of interest, would be to write a [hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) which would set the permissions of all files in the repo to whatever you wanted. That might also give you some assurance that you weren't accidentally leaving a new file with dangerous permissions.

Comment: This worked for me, unlike the accepted answer. And it's a bit counter intuitive - I thoughtI should set it to `true` but even for my case `false` is what I needed.