# Eclipse changes file mode from 644 to 755 on all files it touches

Tags: eclipse, git

I'm using Eclipse under Win7, editing files that are shared from an Ubuntu VirtualBox VM over vboxsf. The files were originally created with file mode 644, but Eclipse is changing files to 755 (even ones that I've not edited).

How can I prevent Eclipse from changing the permissions of files in my repository?

Comment: You might benefit from this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580596/how-do-i-make-git-ignore-mode-changes-chmod

Comment: Sounds more like it is vboxsf that needs to be told that it needs to map Windows permissions differently onto Unix permissions.