# How to skip file permissions in git

Tags: git

What is wrong with my default settings on Linux?

```
rm -rf PATH
mkdir -p PATH
cd PATH

git clone GITPATH .
git status
```

It shows all of the recently downloaded files as *modified*. And I cannot pull *later* on.

```
# On branch master
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

#       modified:   readme.txt
#       modified:   todo.txt
```

Diff

```
git diff todo.txt

diff --git a/todo.txt b/todo.txt
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
```

How can I get rid of this unexpected annoying thing?

Comment: That's definitely weird. Could you add some more details about your environment (e.g. Linux distribution, any significant configuration you may have done, etc.)?

Comment: It is a default whm/cpanel installation upgraded manually later on through web interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a filesystem that supports file permissions. also reading [How do I make Git ignore file mode (chmod) changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580596/how-do-i-make-git-ignore-file-mode-chmod-changes) might help. btw this is certainly not the default for a proper linux installation.

```
git config core.fileMode false
```