# git diff: How to ignore filemode of piped input?

Tags: git, js-beautify

I'm trying to use **git diff** to ensure that my JavaScript has been beautified before committing.

`js-beautify src.js | git -c core.fileMode=false diff --no-index -- src.js -`

I've followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580596/how-do-i-make-git-ignore-file-mode-chmod-changes) for ignoring file mode but I still get this output.

```
diff --git a/src.js b/-
old mode 100755
new mode 100644
index 13158aa..0000000
```

I also tried `git config core.fileMode false` to no avail. If I change permissions of the file and diff against HEAD, the command works as expected (diff is empty).

```
chmod 644 src.js
git -c core.fileMode=false diff -- src.js
```

Is it possible to ignore the permissions of files that aren't indexed? I'm using git version 1.9.1.

Answer (score 2):

One method around that would be something along these lines:

```
js-beautify src.js | diff - <(git show HEAD:./src.js)
```

or alternatively:

```
diff <(js-beautify src.js) <(git show HEAD:./src.js)
```

That won't produce the `git diff` format, but I don't know if that's critical for your particular use case.