# I need to merge a copy of my website with only one commit

Tags: git, github, merge

I have a git repo on github.

Someone has taken the repo (copied, not forked; I'm not entirely sure how or why), done a lot of work on about a quarter of the files therein, and then uploaded a new git repo to their own area in github containing exactly one commit - an initial commit, containing everything.

If I try to git merge, then every single file is coming up as a conflict; it thinks we've both added the files from scratch. Which of course we have.

I could manually diff and merge them all. But I'd really rather not have to.

I've added in his repo as a remote.

Is there an obvious way to merge in only the files which have been changed?

Comment: Could [git patch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch) be suitable for you?

Comment: You could try a `git cherry-pick` from the other repo. You will have to resolve conflicts for each modified file in that commit if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, it looks like the file permissions everywhere in the new commit had changed to 755; that's what was causing everything to be flagged as changed.

[How do I make Git ignore file mode (chmod) changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580596/how-do-i-make-git-ignore-file-mode-chmod-changes) suggests that the problem is solvable by using

```
git config core.fileMode false
```

Unfortunately, this didn't work for me; possibly because it only looks at changes in the working tree rather than in commits.

Instead, I went into the new branch and did the following

```
git diff --summary master | grep  'mode change 100644 => 100755' | cut -d' ' -f7- | xargs -I {} chmod -x {}
```

Which then turned off all of the executable bits in the new branch.

```
git commit -a
git log --oneline

2f80315 Changing permissions to match master...
c7896aa The Commit From The Other Fella

git checkout master
git cherry-pick 2f80315
git commit --allow-empty
```

Makes sure that all of the permissions on every file that wasn't edited match, and at this point a

```
git diff newfellasbranch
```

shows me the changes that they've made. I'm happy, so

```
git merge newfellasbranch --strategy-option theirs
```

There may well be a simpler way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

```
git fetch https://github.com/blah/other-repo.git <branch> && git cherry-pick <commit>
```

It behaves like a merge, if conflicts appear you will have to resolve them manually but only from the modified files.

Comment: There is only one commit in the other repo, which contains everything; so a git cherry-pick is, in this circumstance, identical to a git merge.