# File and directory permissions on a cloned github repository

Tags: git, bash, github, file-permissions

When I use git to clone something like https://github.com/rails/rails I see permissions like the following (bash in OS X 10.10). The files and directories have the permissions I expect.

[image: Rails repo permissions]

But when I pull from a private github repo (owned by my company) I see permissions like the following. I don't understand why the permissions are restricted. Are those the permissions the last developer was using when he/she pushed to Github? (they are no longer with the company)

I can't access anything with my local webserver without changing the permissions on every file and directory. Do I have to change the permissions and then commit those changes? How are permissions normally handled?

[image]

Comment: make git ignore file permission http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580596/how-do-i-make-git-ignore-file-mode-chmod-changes

Comment: In both situations, are you cloning from the same user account on your local system?  Git doesn't *store* file permissions in the repository (other than "is this file executable"), so this would be really puzzling *if* both results are from the same account.

Comment: Yes, I am cloning when logged in as the same user. I am going to follow @bitoiu's advice and "fix" the local permissions (via `chmod`) and then add `filemode = false` to the repo's `.git/config` file.

Answer (score 0):

May be to check [umask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) setting on private server? First correct permissions on private server and [set umask value](http://ss64.com/bash/umask.html) to 0022.