# How do i change file ownership after git commit

Tags: linux, wordpress, git

I have set up a live repo on my server with:

```
/cd/siteusername/public_html/
mkdir site.git
cd site.git
git init —bare
cd hooks
cat > post-receive
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/var/www/domain.com --git-dir=/var/repo/site.git checkout -f
chmod +x post-receive
```

The issue is everytime i push changes from my local repo using:

```
git add .
git commit -m "file change"
git push live master
```

git changes the ownership of all the files in my live repo so i get presented with a 500 error

How can i prevent this happening?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580596/how-do-i-make-git-ignore-file-mode-chmod-changes

Comment: @RabeeAbdelWahab: that is not really answering the OP's question.
NeilM did you get any more useful info? I am seriously struggling here