# How to ensure Linux file ownership correct when pulling from GIT repo

Tags: linux, git, file, permissions

I have reviewed a bunch of useful stuff, but still not clear how to do what I need
([How do i change file ownership after git commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33523764/how-do-i-change-file-ownership-after-git-commit); 
[How to keep git from changing file ownership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076348/how-to-keep-git-from-changing-file-ownership); 
[Making git push respect permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264968/making-git-push-respect-permissions);
[Retaining file permissions with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207728/retaining-file-permissions-with-git))

Given that significant time has gone by, is there now a simple, straightforward solution?

What do *you* do?

**Attempting to:**

- Code/test in windows dev environment (XAMPP)

- Create/manage different code versions (GIT)

- Push code versions to remote repo ... on WAMP server (GIT)

- Checkout different versions from repo into dev and/or into live environments (GIT)

So far, so obvious - core use case for GIT, almost everyone needs to do this?

**BUT complexity:**

- in order to actually run in the live environment (which is kind of the point) files and permissions need to be correct

- code is spread across htdocs (primary site), symlink directory (end-user accessible content like graphics etc), and non-user-accessible source code (held above www root)

- these different areas need different user ownership -> different permissions

**Problem:** as identified in one form or another by all referenced questions:

- Git overwrites file ownership with owner:group of user running the git command, and messes up permissions required to actually run the application

**Ideal Solution:**

- A tool which understands/maintains which ownership settings and permissions are needed for the target environment, e.g. on a directory by directory basis: files in Directory A should have ownerA, groupB and permissions xyzxyzxyz and is able to re-apply them after git messes it all up

**Considered so far:**

OPTION 1: in-Git functionality or flag setting to allow this.

- NO: 'git is not a deployment tool'

OPTION 2: use git-cache-meta to store file settings, then to apply file settings again afterwards.

- NO: files come from Windows dev environment that does not have Unix type permissions, so can't work off incoming permissions

OPTION 3: use (radically under-documented and effectively expert-only) metastore

- NO: from what I can understand, same problem as Option 2

OPTION 4: find, research and experiment with a whole additional set of tools (e.g. Deployer, Gitolite), which appear to be designed to do a whole range of other things and may or may not do what I am looking for

- MAYBE: but, if so: which one can do this? what do you use? what is easy/simple to implement?

OPTION 5: set Group ID on relevant directories to force 'Group' ownership

- NO: this won't help with 'Owner', or permissions

Comment: Why not have a makefile with a "deploy" target, and have the repo elsewhere on the path.

Comment: @Ignacio Potentially, or any automating shell script I suppose ... probably better as a post-receive hook.  I was really hoping for a simpler route than having to write scripts to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Best answer I've found so far:

http://ryansechrest.com/2013/08/managing-file-and-folder-permissions-when-deploying-with-git/#comments