# git shows modified files after clone

Tags: git

After I cloned my repository, *git status* shows modified files. These are images (.png), which it's showing as modified. I've also tried with filemode & CRLF settings, nothing worked. I'm not able to add them or checkout them. I'm on Mac. Here is a screenshot of the *git status* result,

[*git status* result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXwEF.png)

- When I do same git pull or clone on ubuntu system, there are no issues. I just have to set filemode to false there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try git reset, it will undo all checkout

Comment: Why aren't you allowed to add or checkout? What happens when you try?

Comment: @SonalBorkar Tried, but it's not working. It shows same files under 'Unstaged changes after reset:' and nothing else.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy Nothing happens. I do 'git add .' and then again after 'git status' , the result is same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does 'git status' show binary file as modified when it's not and file modes are the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34503622/why-does-git-status-show-binary-file-as-modified-when-its-not-and-file-modes)

Comment: @AbhishekVaishnav Are you using Git LFS? Also, what does `git diff` show?

Comment: @AbhishekVaishnav might need hard reset try below command
     git reset --hard origin/master

Comment: @Bless When I do git diff . it shows result lie this,
diff --git a/application/modules/Advancedactivity/externals/feelings/celebrating/International-Women's-day.png b/application/modules/Advancedactivity/externals/feelings/celebrating/International-Women's-day.png
index a6ab567562..d328e2d057 100644
Binary files a/application/modules/Advancedactivity/externals/feelings/celebrating/International-Women's-day.png and b/application/modules/Advancedactivity/externals/feelings/celebrating/International-Women's-day.png differ

Comment: @SonalBorkar Not working. It's just changing the head, but still showing the modified files.

Comment: @enapupe Yes checked that already, but didn't work out for me, i.e. git reset --hard didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Try below git command in exact sequence as given below

```
 git fetch origin
 git reset --hard origin/master
 git clean -f
 git status
```

Comment: Not working. When I reset --hard, it does show 'unable to unlink old' and filename for all files. I use sudo and it changes head. After clean, when I again checked status, it still shows those files' list.

Comment: ok, that means git couldn't have write permission to the folder where the file resides or the file is accessed by other processes in the system.

Well, you may anytime delete the folder manually outside of git and then again do the git reset --hard and then git pull followed by git status