# Git is not ignoring file mode changes (chmod), why?

Tags: git, ignore

Before start I should say I already looked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580596/how-do-i-make-git-ignore-file-mode-chmod-changes) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39038062/git-is-not-ignoring-file-permission-changes) as well but for some reason the solutions provided there aren't working for me. My repository is under `~/sources` so every command was run from that path. This is what I have done:

Change the filemode to false:

```
$ git config --global core.filemode false
```

Check global configuration:

```
$ git config --list
...
core.filemode=false
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
...
```

Reinitialize the repository:

```
$ git init
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/rperez/sources/.git/
```

Check what needs to be added|committed:

```
$ git status
```

And I get a list having all the files from the repository.

I am using:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.9.3
```

**UPDATE: added git diff for two different files**

```
$ git status
...
    modified:   testing/test-valid-swasset-update.php
...
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    library/mpdf60/ttfontdata/dejavusanscondensedI.GDEFdata.php
...
```

`git diff` output from the files above:

```
$ git diff testing/test-valid-swasset-update.php
diff --git a/testing/test-valid-swasset-update.php b/testing/test-valid-swasset-update.php
old mode 100755
new mode 100644
```

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Local config overrides global config settings

The diff output in the question indicates that the *local* git config has `filemode` set to true. This is probably expected behavior since the default config created for a repo defines this:

```
-> git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/foo/.git/
-> cat .git/config 
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
```

Changing the global config for `filemode` does not affect this, and so in fact `git config --global core.filemode false` doesn't do anything because this is always overridden locally.

Therefore, to change the filemode for this repo, change the local config:

```
$ git config core.filemode false
$ git config core.filemode
false
```

Given [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30578611/761202) there's a possibility it is supposed to work, although it didn't for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can verify what the local setting is with this:
git config --local --list

...and set a local value like this:

git config --local core.filemode false