# git checkout -b dev origin/dev being stopped by file I can't stash or ignore

Tags: git

I have just cloned the repo from a project I'm working on.  We clone from the *master but then I need to checkout and create a local dev branch as the is what we commit our code to and the *master is locked to commits.   As soon as the clone finished I did git status and find that there is a

```
user@directory:~/dirName/dirName$git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working 
directory)

modified:   .htaccess
```

file that is downloaded as well.  I made no changes to this file, I haven't even opened a single file yet.

I need to do a git checkout -b dev origin/dev to create a local branch of origin/dev but this file is stopping me from doing it.

I have done a git stash and it won't stash.  I have tried to assume-unchanged and this still won't allow the checkout to take place. I have also tried to do the git checkout .htaccess and this does nothing. It's also not a file I can commit or push as we can't push to the master.  I also did a hard reset.  I have looked and looked but cannot find this particular scenario.

Is there a way to force the checkout so I can create the /dev branch and make it my default?  Or how can I clear this file out?

I truly appreciate any inputs or guidance as I've not run across this before.  Thank you!

Oh and I use git via CLI not any GUI's.

Comment: are you able to fork that repository?

Comment: Check if this file is occupied by some other program or if the repo has another file whose name is the same except the letter case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and clone again, after typing:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

If the same file is still "modified", check the git diff output to see what kind of difference it has with the HEAD.
Another possible [diff reason would be a permission one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1580644/6309).