# Xcode shows all files as modified when committing from synced machine

Tags: xcode, git

I have my Xcode project files and their git directories on a Dropbox-like syncing service. I made some changes to a few files on my laptop, committed the updates, then allowed the machine to sync.

Then I went to my desktop and allowed the syncing service to update the files, made one small change and tried to commit. Xcode showed all files as having been modified.

Am I using Xcode, Git, and Sync incorrectly? I realize now that syncing and Git is probably redundant functionality, but my question is:

Why does Xcode show every file as having been modified?

Comment: I don't know what "_syncing_" service you're using, but it's somehow modifying all your files when it "_syncs_". What shows up when you `git diff` the modified files? In any case, stop using git and sync at the same time.

Comment: Hi Gino, thanks for this. Indeed, my sync service (sync.com) has changed permissions on files from 755 to 655. I'm not sure why, but I'll need to take that up with sync.com.

Comment: You could [try ignoring file permission changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580596/how-do-i-make-git-ignore-file-mode-chmod-changes).

Comment: @GinoMempin, thanks a lot, ignoring file permission changes helped me