# Eclipse and Git command line are showing different status for files

Tags: eclipse, git

I have recently migrated to GIT from SVN and in the learning phase.
I am working on a change and for that I have created a new branch as below with eclipse option as:

*Right click on project-->Team-->Switch To-->New Branch*

**New branch name :**
feature/Fix-Issues

Say for instance, I have modified two files as part of the fix as :

```
A.java
B.java
```

After doing my changes, I have committed the files with eclipse '**Commit and Push**'. 
I can see a new entry has been added in the history. So far so good.

I am using Cygwin for using git commands. In order to verify that I have checked out to my feature branch, I have issued below command:

```
git branch
```

Which says that I am checked out to my feature branch *(feature/Fix-Issues)*.

Now, if I ran below command:

```
git status
```

It returns as **Changes not staged for commit** :

```
modified:<package>/A.java
modified:<package>/B.java
```

I am not able to understand this part as I have checked in the files from Eclipse and have successful commit message in the history as well.
Any lead would be really helpful.

Comment: Do you have the same repository being cloned in other places anywhere?

Comment: No, the same repository has not been cloned anywhere.

Comment: Did you *add* those two files before you *Commit and Pushed*?

Comment: Yes, Files are present as I can see in the history.

Comment: This sounds like an end-of-line (CRLF) issue. It's possible Eclipse is going behind Git's back and defeating Git's detection that work-tree files with CRLF endings are actually the same as index versions that have LF-only endings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to **filemode** . I have made **filemode=false** . Please have a look on below link [How do I make Git ignore file mode (chmod) changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580596/how-do-i-make-git-ignore-file-mode-chmod-changes)

Answer (score 2):

Since you were saying like you haven't cloned the same repository anywhere else. It might be because of the local repository not updated properly. Try the following options:

**1. Updating the branch**

```
 git checkout your_branch
```

**2. Take a pull/fetch**

`git pull` will pull the latest changes.

`git fetch` will update the list of changes.

Comment: _git pull_  : returns Already up to date.                                                           _git fetch_ : executed successfully with out any messsage. Run _git status_ shown same message _Changes not staged for commit_