# IntelliJ git checkin setting file mode to +X

Tags: git, intellij-idea

**IntelliJ Version:** Ultimate 2018.3

Every time I checkin files to git repo, I notice that all the files permission is changed to executable `(+x)`.

I tried running `git config core.fileMode false` but that has not helped.

What settings can I apply so it doesn't happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executed the following command which has fixed the issue:

> *git config --global core.filemode false*

Reference:

- https://github.com/Gizra/KnowledgeBase/wiki/How-to-set-Git-to-ignore-chmod-changes
- [How do I make Git ignore file mode (chmod) changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580596/how-do-i-make-git-ignore-file-mode-chmod-changes)