# Git status gives different results in cygwin and git bash (windows 10)

Tags: windows, git, cygwin

I have installed cygwin (and git using the cygwin package manager) and [git](https://git-scm.com/) bash for windows.

I have just cloned a repository using cygwin shell and then opened a git bash shell and a cygwin shell in the root of the repository.

Then I execute `git status` from each shell. Git bash finds a change (file permission) but cygwin does NOT and I am trying to understand why.

Below are the details:

**Git Bash (show modified file)**

```
$ git --version
git version 2.23.0.windows.1
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   script.sh

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

$ git diff
diff --git a/script.sh b/script.sh
old mode 100755
new mode 100644

$ git config -l | grep core
core.symlinks=true
core.autocrlf=false
core.fscache=true
core.editor='C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin
core.editor='C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -nosession
core.autocrlf=false
core.preloadindex=true
core.fscache=true
core.filemode=true
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
```

**Cygwin (no changes found)**

```
$ git --version
git version 2.21.0
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

$ git config -l | grep core
core.editor='C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -nosession
core.autocrlf=false
core.preloadindex=true
core.fscache=true
core.filemode=true
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
```

So for both shells `core.filemode=true`.

Any suggestions to why git bash picks up the file permission change?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
git config core.filemode false 
git config core.autocrlf true
```

If that resolves the problem, than line ending settings were the problem.

In case the changes are reported as `typechange`, then the problem might be the simlinks, and the solution:

```
git config core.symlinks true
```

Also, make sure to apply those settings locally in the mentioned repo, not just globally.

Comment: Try to add more information, how this answers the question.

Answer (score -1):

Issue this command

```
git config core.fileMode false
```

in both repos.

See [How do I make Git ignore file mode (chmod) changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580596/how-do-i-make-git-ignore-file-mode-chmod-changes)

Comment: But I don't want git to ignore chmod changes - also it does not really answer my question of why the difference.

Comment: Windows and POSIX filemodes are not symmetrical. The Window model has a much finer granularity than the POSIX user/group/other X read/write/execute model. Notice that an `ls -l` shows a + after the rwx bits which indicates there are more ACLs in effect than can be shown by the POSIX model.