# git config core.filemode false not working git 2.25.1

Tags: git

I read this solution [How do I make Git ignore file mode (chmod) changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580596/how-do-i-make-git-ignore-file-mode-chmod-changes) and tried a number of other things but the following keeps happening:

When I do

```
git status -v
```

It shows

```
diff --git a/video.html b/video.html
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
```

So it's picking up changes in file permissions, but when I run the following command to make it ignore file changes

```
git config core.filemode false
```

It still sees the changes. Am I doing something wrong or misunderstanding how filemode works?

I also tried changing global git settings, modifying the .git/config file etc to set filemode to false but nothing works, it still sees the changes.

### Manual permission change via git update-index

The only workaround I found for now is by going to repo folder and doing something like `git update-index --chmod=-x FILENAME` with a recursive approach

```
git ls-files --stage | grep 100755 | cut -f2 | xargs git update-index --chmod=-x
```

But this does not cover all of the files unfortunately

### "Solution"

In the end had to do a hard reset from master to fix the issue. Think the problem was that I committed that files with changed permissions BEFORE doing the `git config core.filemode false` and once committed I'm assuming it was somewhere in git cache and there was no way to ignore the permissions with any sort of filemode change.

Comment: Post complete output. My `git status -v` does not show `diff --git ...`. Did you mean to run `git config core.filemode false` (note the `false`)?

Comment: @j6t yep, my mistake I ran the `git config core.filemode false` + variations of it to set it on a global level and also to changed it in  `.git/config` etc. In terms of the output complete output from git status -v is over a thousand lines, but the `diff --git` is definitely from there

Answer (score 1):

Update: the question is modified now; here's what I think the real answer is:

- Your file system doesn't actually support modes.
- You did actually set `core.filemode` to `true` at some point.
- This made Git believe the results from the `lstat` call.  That updated a bunch of index entries to have `mode 100755` (probably).
- This in turn had Git make a commit with the wrong modes in it.
- After that, you fixed `core.filemode` (put it back to `false`) and perhaps updated Git's index as well (note that Git's index retains any +x or -x setting that gets *set* in it, whether that comes from trusting-`lstat`-and-seeing-`x`-bits-in-the-working-tree, or from `git update-index --chmod`, or whatever, until some other operation comes along and updates Git's index).

Once things *get* messy, the fix tends to be messy too.

Original answer below.

---

`git config core.filemode` *means* `git config --get core.filemode`, i.e., *tell me what `core.filemode` is set to*.  It will not *change* the setting.

As noted in the accepted answer to the question you linked to, the command to *set* it is:

```
git config core.filemode false
```

(you can spell `core.filemode` with partial or full uppercase if you like; this particular bit of Git is case-insensitive).  **In general, however, you should never *set* `core.filemode` at all.**  Having to do so indicates that something else on your system is misbehaving.  You should fix the other thing instead.

Comment: hi, sorry it was a typo on my end, it's the command in the question title which i tried git config core.filemode false and variations such as setting in on a global level etc.

Comment: @RobertSinclair: typos are one of the little devils (imps?) of programming and hence programming questions: it's usually a good idea to try the command and cut-and-paste both it and its output. :-)

Comment: amen to that! sorry for the time wasted!