# Adding Bash Scripts to Git from Windows - Set Executable Bit

Tags: bash, git, git-for-windows

Is there a way to automatically set the execution bit upon committing a new bash script from a Windows machine?

The manual way to do it is `git update-index --chmod=+x myscript.sh` - but this is typically only done postmortem after the build process fails on the linux box due to missing execute permission on the script.

Comment: You may be able to do it in commit hook.

Comment: I definitely think it could be done in a commit hook, but then the hook has to be installed manually, which is a different issue. My initial thought is to put a hook on the server that rejects a commit with `.sh` files not marked executable, but then that creates still a different set of problems.

Comment: When I said `commit hook`, I didn't mean `rejects a commit with .sh files not marked executable`. I wonder if commit hook can enforce the setting of executable bits.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580596/how-do-i-make-git-ignore-file-mode-chmod-changes could be helpful?

Comment: @WyattCarpenter - there's probably the start of an answer in there somewhere. Thanks for the pointer.