# git, whitespace errors, squelching and autocrlf, the definitive answers

Tags: git, whitespace, newline

Please can you explain about whitespace errors in git, what do they mean, what is 'squelching', and do I need to worry about it?

(Running msysgit, but with other users on linux).

*There is already a 'definitive' answer for autocrlf [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016673/definitive-recommendation-for-git-autocrlf-settings)* (set it to false `git config --global core.autocrlf false`
)

Comment: And a 'definitive' answer for whitespace errors [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396622/what-does-1-line-adds-whitespace-errors-mean-when-applying-a-patch/12396793#12396793).

Answer (score 34):

[Squelching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squelch) is initially a function used in telecommunication to set a threshold above which a signal is or isn't alllowed through.

In your case, when you see:

```
warning: squelched 104 whitespace errors
warning: 109 lines add whitespace errors.
```

It means: instead of displaying 100+ error messages, it warns you it should have displayed those errors (but it won't, in order to not clutter the output)

I have no definitive recommendations for whitespace policy, except from identifying why they are introduced in the first place.
If your editor doesn't convert the eol (end of lines) characters between Window and Unix, then it means it somehow add or remove automatically whitespaces, which is not always useful.

A first test (as in this [blog post](http://stubbisms.wordpress.com/2008/07/30/git-rebase-svn-and-whitespace/)) is to de-activate the policy:

```
git config core.whitespace nowarn
```

or try

```
git config core.whitespace fix
```

and see if that facilitates your rebase operations.

Comment: So, something like my editor converting tabs to spaces would show as an error? (Actually, it wasn't a rebase that gave me this message, it was re-applying a stash - it didn't prevent the re-apply, but I wanted to understand the message)

Comment: @Benjol: in this case, the 'squelch' message is there to warn you there will be trouble in future merge situations (merge, rebase, push to, pull from)

Comment: I"core.whitespace no warn" didn't work for me. Do I have to restart machine or terminal or something?

Comment: @kakyo No,but the value should be nowarn (in one word), and not "no warn".

Comment: I did use one word nowarn (it was probably the spellcheck of safari that messed up my comment). But I still see lots of whitespace related warnings, such as "trailing whitespace".

Comment: @kakyo : see my answer below, I think it will help you.

Answer (score 17):

Here is how to fix "trailing whitespace" errors when using git apply :

The first thing you need to know is : what is a whitespace error. This is explained on the [core.whitespace setting documentation](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration). Basically, git handles several kind of whitespace errors :

```
blank-at-eol
blank-at-eof
space-before-tab
indent-with-non-tab
tab-in-indent
cr-at-eol
```

*trailing whitespace* error can rise when patching a file using windows style line ending (CRLF).
To avoid this warning, you can either ask `git apply` to not show warning :

```
git apply --whitespace=nowarn fix.patch
```

or you can edit git configuration **on the fly** (with `-c`) to say "ok git, CR at end of line are fine this time" :

```
git -c core.whitespace=cr-at-eol apply fix.patch
```

If you want to make it **permanent**, just edit the git configuration like that :

```
git config apply.whitespace nowarn
```

or :

```
git config core.whitespace cr-at-eol
```

Answer (score 14):

After searching for that answer as well and looking into both the git-config and git-apply manuals, I found that

```
git config apply.whitespace nowarn
```

deactivates showing the whitespace errors in your current repository.

To make it available for all the repositories just add `--global` like this:

```
git config --global apply.whitespace nowarn
```

Comment: `core.whitespace` didn't work for me but `apply.whitespace` worked. In my case, applying a diff was throwing whitespace warnings `git apply file.diff`.