# Git committing unchanged files

Tags: git, commit, egit

Long story short, I have a situation where egit allows unchanged files to be committed.  If I commit, will this corrupt the git repository?

Comment: Is it `git` or the user claiming the files are "unchanged"?

Comment: I'm pretty certain this question is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3459448/how-do-i-stop-git-from-committing-unchanged-files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unchanged files are always committed in git. Each commit is the entire tree of files along with a commit message. Unless you have a specific strange situation which is not adequately captured by the description "unchanged files" there will be no problem.

Comment: Would like to just add one thing: the files are stored only once. This is determined by their contents' hash. So there is no disk space that is inefficiently used.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions specifically, `git commit` commits those files in the index, including files that are unchanged from what is in the repository.  There are several ways to include a file in the index (see the `git-commit` man page).

Git commits files based upon their hash code; if it is unchanged (as would be the case if the files are truly unchanged), then nothing is stored.  But in any event, whether or not a file is unchanged when committed, a `git commit` will not corrupt the repository.