# Why Git adds - and + to all of my code?

Tags: git, diff

Sometimes for example I change a word in line 100 and delete last 4 lines.
When I run "git diff" It shows a log which has a -(minus) and +(plus) before all lines whereas I changed only mentioned lines.
I thought it may be due to changing number of all lines but when I saw the changes again I didn't see any change to line numbers.

so what cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just formatting to show what lines have been changed (added/removed/etc).  Those +s and -s are not actually in your files.

Comment: Ahh ok.  Yeah its probably a CRLF mismatch.  Check your autocrlf settings.

Comment: Thanks.but do you know how do I change autocrlf settings?

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't wrapped my head around the best thing to do with the AutoCRLF setting.  Here's some background reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016673/definitive-recommendation-for-git-autocrlf-settings

Comment: My understanding is that you're better off getting your editor to do the right thing and not having to mess with autocrlf.

Answer (score 3):

Which text editor are you using? Perhaps it changed line endings between Unix/DOS. (i.e. LF to CR+LF)

Comment: I'm using Netbeans in windows.if it's the problem how do I solve it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with NetBeans, but I found this link: http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqEditorEOLs