# I have problems with central git archive since I set gitattributes to handle crlf

Tags: linux, windows, macos, git, newline

This is related to [Force LF eol in git repo and working copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976986/force-lf-eol-in-git-repo-and-working-copy)

When I do a git clone, and then a git pull, there are deltas, which IMO shouldn't be there for correct operation.
This started when I added a gitattributes file, which I added because one file had 2 kinds of line endings. The systems used by us are windows and Mac clients and a linux server from which git stuff gets pulled from and pushed to.
Do you have any advice? origin should be at HEAD always, shouldn't it?
It also might be relevant that the central git archive feeds a webserver using checkout and force.

```
$ git pull
remote: Counting objects: 469, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (391/391), done.
remote: Total 392 (delta 282), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (392/392), 94.48 KiB, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (282/282), completed with 46 local objects.
```

Comment: It seems the crlf-conversion takes place when cloning and does not reflect a problem with the central git origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by not using .gitattribute