# Line endings issue between Mac and Windows

Tags: git

I have a MacBook and am running Windows in a Parallels VM.  My development is primarily in Visual Studio, but I like to use Git with the Mac shell (just like it better than what is available for Windows).

When I do a git diff to determine what has changed between commits I am getting the proverbial line ending "changes" that make git think much more has changed than actually has.

I know this is an age old problem, and I have done a lot of research with varying suggestions from a lot of people, but I am not able to solve this issue.  The most promising information was found in this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510798/trying-to-fix-line-endings-with-git-filter-branch-but-having-no-luck/1511273#1511273) but it didn't solve my issue.

Here are some relevant lines from my .gitconfig...

```
[core]
    autocrlf = false
    safecrlf = false
```

Also, I have a .gitattributes in the root of my repo that only contains...

```
* text eol=crlf
```

What can I do to make Git stop thinking line ending changes are real changes when performing a diff?  Again, I am using a Mac shell to look at Windows files, so this might be part of my issue.

Thanks!

Comment: have you been able to solve this? It is plaguing my team as well. Driving me crazy.

Comment: I just started using Git from the Windows side.  I was not able to resolve it.  But using Git from the Windows side avoids the problem.

Comment: Any chance you guys solved this?

Answer (score 2):

I alias `gdiff` to:

```
git diff -w origin/`git branch | sed --quiet "s/* \(.*\)/\1/p"`
```

but you can just do:

```
git diff -w
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a conversion utility eg Perl, `perl -i -pne "s/\n/\r\n/g"` filename

or `unix2dos` and `dos2unix`.

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Conversion_utilities

For configuration of GIT see another answer: [Force LF eol in git repo and working copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976986/force-lf-eol-in-git-repo-and-working-copy)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I want to keep the CRLF line endings on the Windows files, but when looking at the differences from the Mac side with git, not see a different line ending as a change.  I think the conversion utility would actually change the line endings.