# How to clean up line-endings with Git

Tags: git, eol

I'm quite inexperienced with Git, and this one baffles me:

I just switched my working copy to another branch (a simple `git checkout master`), and immediately after that, `git status` tells me about hundreds of changed files.  However, it's all about line endings;  a `git diff --ignore-space-at-eol` gives me a lot of warnings:

```
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in src/.../somefile.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
```

I generally consider it a bad idea to have DOS-style line endings in versioned text files, but this is what they have been committed like in the first place;  I did this in a Linux box, and the files I got have CRLF line endings.

What is the best way to clean up in my situation?  Should I change the line ending of every single file and commit this?

How can Git be configured to avoid such situations in the future?

Comment: As already mentioned, Git is capable of automatically handling line-ending issues on commits with the `core.autocrlf` setting. This **[question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825428/why-should-i-use-core-autocrlf-true-in-git)** has a great answer that might assist you in deciding whether or not that option is for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force LF eol in git repo and working copy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976986/force-lf-eol-in-git-repo-and-working-copy)

Comment: Ok, the 2nd part is answered - in many places, as I see it.  As for the 1st part of my question, there seems to be no solution but to commit sanitized data (the CRLF files are from a cloned Github repo) and hope for the best.

Answer (score 2):

Try one of these out (depending on your OS):

```
// Windows
git config --global core.autocrlf true

// Linux, OSX
git config --global core.autocrlf input
```

Comment: I tried it (the Linux version, both with and without `--global`) and switched to the other branch and back again (`git checkout -f ...`), but it seems to be too late for my working copy ... Should I kill it completely and clone it anew?

Comment: I'm surprised git didn't figure it out right away. But if that's an option you have, then (safely) try it out.

Comment: Perhaps because of the Git version? This is a Debian box, and I have Git v1.7.10.4, while 1.8.4.1 is the current version.

Answer (score 2):

As I [mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2825829/6309), I prefer:

- leaving global transformation option set to false (git config core.autocrlf false)
- setting [eol directive in `.gitattributes` files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2354278/6309) for specific files or file extensions.

Whatever solution you choose, check out the "[Trying to fix line-endings with git filter-branch, but having no luck](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1510798/6309)" to fix your current index.
In particular, test the [removal of the `.git/index` file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4683783/6309), followed by a `git reset`.