# how to transition from using eol CRLF to LF across repos with .gitattributes file

Tags: git

We are currently developing on both Windows and Unix like platforms. On Windows platforms we have the following settings:

```
core.eol = native
core.autocrlf = true
```

I'm considering moving away from `CRLF` eol and using `LF` on all platforms. What are the steps I should take to make that transition less troublesome?

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976986/force-lf-eol-in-git-repo-and-working-copy) that the following should be set in config:

```
$ git config core.eol lf
$ git config core.autocrlf input
```

But as I've read [here](http://adaptivepatchwork.com/2012/03/01/mind-the-end-of-your-line/) these settings are from the old git system. We're are using version `1.9.4` and I believe we should be using `.gitattributes` file to set line endings.

Comment: I have simlar issue, in linux it use `LF` as default, but when switch to windows, some IDE always ask whether to convert `LF` to `CRLF`, that's bothering.

Comment: @EricWang, well, most IDE's can be configured to use a particular eol, for example IDEA editors can be configured to use LF as eol