# Forcing all line endings to LF for git

Tags: git, newline, core.autocrlf

I develop for both Windows and linux.  My Linux development environment is a virtual box running on my windows hosts.  i have some directories shared (actually suing samba, not the built-in virtual box shared folders, so the directory is actually on the linux guest and shared up to the host)

We are moving from svn to git.  I want to run Source Tree on my windows machine (the linux is headless) to do the version control.  But I want all the files to have linux line endings (LF).

I tried following the instructions at [Force LF eol in git repo and working copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976986/force-lf-eol-in-git-repo-and-working-copy) but they aren't working for me.

I have set the config as follows:

```
[adamc@adamc-centos scripts]$ git config core.autocrlf
input
[adamc@adamc-centos scripts]$ git config  core.eol
lf
```

I have the following in my .gitattributes (even forced .sh to be text fioles and specified the eol again)

```
* text=auto
*.sh    text eol=lf
```

I have run the checkout-index command specified there, and I still have .sh files with windows line endings!

```
[adamc@adamc-centos scripts]$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working directory clean

[adamc@adamc-centos scripts]$ git checkout-index --force --all
[adamc@adamc-centos scripts]$ ./EWEB/get_unmerged.sh
-bash: ./EWEB/get_unmerged.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

What have I missed?  Or am I approaching it wrong?

Comment: `core.eol` is ignored if you set `core.autocrlf` to `true` or `input`  https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coreeol

Answer (score -2):

If you use different operating systems the recommended settings are

- for windows
  `$ git config --global core.autocrlf true`
- for linux/mac
  `git config --global core.autocrlf input`

I don't think you need to define parameter `core.eol` or use file `.gitattributes`. Git properly detects text files by default.

How to make commit that fixes all line endings in repository you can find at github page https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings

If you migrate your repository with git-svn probably it's good idea to rewrite the whole history and fix line endings in all commits.

Comment: I *want* to check out on Windows but with linux line endings.  As I understand it the default/recommended settings are to achieve the opposite: that you always have the native line endings for the place you check out.