# "Please make sure all files only have LF endings" error when pushing to a GitHub repo

Tags: git, github, lf

I am new to Git. I forked a repo, created a branch, made some changes, committed and then when I push (git push origin master), I get the following error :

```
     Starting Pattern Checks

    .gitattributes --> Please make sure all files only have LF endings (no CRLF).
     core/templates/dev/head/dashboard/notifications_dashboard.html --> Please use spaces instead of tabs.

     (41 files checked, 2 errors found)
     FAILED   Pattern checks failed
     Push failed, please correct the linting issues above
```

I am running git on Windows 7. Can anyone please help me ? Thanks.

PS: I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976986/force-lf-eol-in-git-repo-and-working-copy) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967370/git-replacing-lf-with-crlf)

UPDATE : The 'Please use spaces instead of tabs.' error was corrected by converting TAB to Spaces in 'Edit->Blank Operations->TAB to space' for Notepad++.

Comment: What editor are you using to make the changes?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I am using Notepad++.

Comment: After having fixed the line endings, have you looked at "*Please use spaces instead of tabs.*"?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I converted the tabs to spaces by going to Edit -> Blank Operations -> TAB to Space and then tried pushing again. The second error has been solved. But the LF endings error still persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means that the project requires Unix-style line endings (LF). However, you are using Windows-style line endings (CRLF). All decent programming text editors and IDEs have an option to set this. Editors also have an option to quickly replace all CRLF sequences with just LF. You need to find out how to do this in yours.

I also suggest that you learn about branching in git. If you are contributing to a larger project, it will be required that you create a new branch for each related set of changes that you want to make. Committing directly to `master` is seriously frowned upon.

Comment: The few files in the repository show LF already as line endings when I click "Show End of Line" in Notepad++.

Comment: @user2125722 The error message states specifically which files cause the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Done ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

In Notepad++, go to the View menu > Show Symbol > Show End of Line.
now press CTRL + H, make sure the Extended search mode is selected, and replace all \r\n with \n

Save. now try.

[image]

P.S: as Bergi also suggested, you may also automate both of your requirements via notepad by going to:

the Edit Menu>Blank Operations> Tab to Space

the Edit menu>EOL Conversion> UNIX/OSX Format

Comment: The few files in the repository show LF already as line endings when I click "Show End of Line" in Notepad++. Also, how do I check if all files in my repository have LF endings ?

Comment: Much simpler than a custom search&replace: Edit menu > Line endings > Convert to LF

Comment: like Bergi said in the comments, make sure core/templates/dev/head/dashboard/notifications_dashboard.html has no tabs in it, only spaces.

Comment: @Bergi I converted the tabs to spaces by going to Edit -> Blank Operations -> TAB to Space and then tried pushing again. The second error has been solved. But the 'Please make sure all files are LF endings' error still persists.