# Git: when to use eol, autocrlf, text?

Tags: git, eol, core.autocrlf

I am learning to program cross-platform with java, git and eclipse. I read a lot about line endings but I am not sure exactly how to use what. [The article of Tim Clem](http://adaptivepatchwork.com/2012/03/01/mind-the-end-of-your-line/) states it very simple: when `core.eol` is set to `native`, you get crlf in windows and lf in unix like environments and git translates between the two. That's what I want. However, [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976986/force-lf-eol-in-git-repo-and-working-copy) asks me to set `core.autocrlf true`. [Another article](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration) asked me to set it to `true` on windows and `input` on linux. [According to the man pages](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) this overrides core.eol and I do not see the use of that. It adds an extra level of making mistakes.

Next one should start the `.gitattributes` file with `* text=auto` and define what exactly text is. What I have trouble to understand is that when the setting of `core.eol native` seems to be satisfactory, why I should define `autocrlf` or `.gitattributes`? As far as I can see Git handles all the conversions and is clever enough to determine which file is text and which is binary. If I do not trust Git's decision making I may specify exactly which files are text and which not in `.gitattributes`. But why should I define `* auto true` when `core.eol` is `native`?

My question: if `core.eol native` is insufficient for working cross platform, why is that the case? I am obviously missing some point, but I could not find it out reading the docs because different articles and man pages say different things. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you will get allinfo here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206843/how-line-ending-conversions-work-with-git-core-autocrlf-between-different-operat

Comment: I refer to the article of Tim Clem, he simply does not explain why `core.autocrlf` is necessary when already `core.eol` is defined.

Comment: `autocrlf` is a legacy settings. It *can* override the newer mechanisms for legacy reasons. If you leave it at the default (`false`) then it won’t do anything.

Comment: Ah, `core.eol native` and `core.autocrlf false` will have the desired behavior on both windows and linux). What is the added value of  `* text auto` in the `.gitattributes` file?

Comment: With `autocrlf = false`, you *need* to configure line endings in the `.gitattributes` in order to have line ending conversion (which will then respect the `eol` setting).