# git - CRLF issue in windows + linux dual boot

Tags: linux, windows, git, core.autocrlf

*I'm going to answer my question with the fix what solved my problem.*

***Note for downvoters**: I understand that the root cause is discussed in various other threads (that is how I solved my problem). This post is more about how having a dual boot system can lead you to this issue. So **no, this question/answer is not a duplicate**, but a particular instance of a general class of problems, adding more cases to SO's repository on this issue.*

---

**At home**: I code in Linux. `LF` used as line ending
**At the office**: I code in windows. `CRLF` used as line endings.

By default, git's `autocrlf` feature (https://stackoverflow.com/a/20653073/2715083) keeps things happy.

However, if you run a dual boot system with Linux and Windows, you can mess yourself up in the following way:

1. `git pull` some files you worked on in a linux environment in a windows environment, in a location that can be accessed from the dual-booted linux environment. This modifies the files to contain `CRLF` endings.
2. Then when you open up the file in linux, where the default is only `LF`, `git diff` will say **entire file is modified**, because each `LF` got changed to `CRLF` at every single line. (I was warned by Atom, which has this diff count inbuilt)

Comment: These issues have already been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967370/git-replacing-lf-with-crlf?noredirect=1&lq=1), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206843/how-line-ending-conversions-work-with-git-core-autocrlf-between-different-operat) and in plenty of other threads. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29888735/365237) is a clean way of working around if you want your files re-checked out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git replacing LF with CRLF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967370/git-replacing-lf-with-crlf)

Comment: @eis be so kind as to see my edit :)

Comment: I still think this is a duplicate, already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967370/git-replacing-lf-with-crlf/29888735#29888735) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976986/force-lf-eol-in-git-repo-and-working-copy/42135910#42135910), for example.

Comment: @eis okay cool. As long as it helps someone, being a duplicate doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> you are talking about text=auto part? I wasn't sure If  I need to include that in a new `.gitattributes` file or not, because when I did, **ATOM still showed the files as modified**.

Yes, it does.
To force Git to apply `.gitattributes` directives, see "[Dealing with line endings](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/#refreshing-a-repository-after-changing-line-endings)".

I would first make sure `core.autocrlf` is set to false.

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

Then:

```
git add . -u
git commit -m "Saving files before refreshing line endings"

rm .git/index

git reset

git status

git add -u
git add .gitattributes

git commit -m "Normalize all the line endings"
```

You can also use, to force the index re-normalization:

```
git rm --cached -r .
git reset --hard
```

See "[Force LF eol in git repo and working copy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42135910/6309)"

```
* text=auto eol=lf
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed steps! By forcing all line endings to be `LF`, will it  cause any problems in windows kinda places where `CRLF` is the norm?

Comment: @Somjit It depends on the type of file and of your IDE. You can restrict the `* text=auto eol=lf` to `*.xxx` (a certain extension)

Comment: Yeah, I guess most code editors will be okay. Thanks for pointing out the custom extension mod.

Answer (score -1):

**The FIX**

1. Delete/move to another location the problem files/folders
2. do `git checkout <hash> <your/files/location>`

where `<hash>` is for the last good commit, and `your/files/location` being the location of the files you want to *cure* from the `CRLF` problem. This will basically restore the older versions from your local `.git` repository.

Worked for me.

*If you know something i missed, or explained incorrectly, do let me know*

Comment: You are circumventing the problem. To really fix it, use a '.gitattributes' file

Comment: @Philippe you are talking about `text=auto` part? I wasn't sure If i need to include that in a new `.gitattributes` file or not, because when I did, ATOM still showed the files as modified...